# Sending and receiving data with socket

Tags: python, sockets

i am trying to send both audio and text from server side to client side with socket. However, there is a problem. If I try to send the audio with `text_receive` enabled, meaningless phrases come out. how can i fix it?

Voice and text sending functions on the server side:

```
def send_audio(self):
        p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                        channels=self.CHANNELS,
                        rate=self.RATE,
                        input=True,
                        frames_per_buffer=self.CHUNK)
        
        Esik_deger = 10 
        while True:

            data = stream.read(self.CHUNK)
            audio_data = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.int16)
            if np.abs(audio_data).mean() > Esik_deger: # mikrofona gelen ses verilerin MUTLAK değerinin ortalamasını alarak ses şiddetini buluyoruz. ortalama, eşik değerinden yüksekse ses iletim devam ediyor.
                mikrofon = True
            else:
                mikrofon  = False
            
            
            try:
                    if self.is_running and mikrofon:
                    
                        converted_data = signal.resample(audio_data, int(len(audio_data) * self.PITCH_SHIFT_FACTOR)) * 1.4
                        converted_data = converted_data.astype(np.int16)
                        converted_data_bytes = converted_data.tobytes()
                        self.client_socket.sendall(converted_data_bytes)

                    if not self.is_running:
                            return
            except Exception as e:
                    if self.client_socket is not None and self.contunie == True:
                        print("bir hata oldu : ",e)
                        print("yeniden bağlanılmaya çalışılıyor...")
                        self.client_socket.close()
                        self.client_socket, address = self.server_socket.accept()
                        print(f"* {address} adresinden yeni bir bağlantı alındı.")
                        
   
        stream.stop_stream()
        stream.close()
        self.client_socket.close()
        p.terminate()

def send_text(self):

        metin = self.text_place.get("1.0", tk.END).strip()
        if metin:
            self.client_socket.send(metin.encode("utf-8"))
```

Text receiving function on client side:

```
def receive_text(self):
       
           while self.is_running_recv:
            try:
                data = self.server_socket.recv(1024)
                if not data:
                    break
                metin = data.decode("utf-8")
                self.metin_yeri.insert(tk.END, metin + "\n")
                self.metin_yeri.see(tk.END)  # Scrollbar ile otomatik olarak en sona inmesini sağlar
                self.root.update()  # GUI'yi güncellemek için root penceresini yeniler
            except ConnectionResetError:
                break
```